# Tableau UI automation

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, uiautomation

Selenium does not recognize webelements of Tableau. Is there any tool which is successful for UI automation of Tableau ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two commercial options:

- https://kinesis-ci.com

Kinesis is a test framework that adds automated testing and continuous integration capability to your Tableau Server.

- https://www.datagaps.com/bi-testing-tools/bi-validator/automate-tableau-testing/

BI Validator makes use of our patented ELV Architecture to automate BI Testing. It supports extraction of reports and report metadata from Business Intelligence tools such as OBIEE, Tableau, Cognos and Business Objects. The reports are loaded into a repository (Oracle and PostgreSQL) so that validations can be run on it.